# How to share data between a page and a component in AEM 6.2?

Tags: aem, sling-models

Is there a way how I can call the same instance of a model within HTL using the same data?
I want to create an object within the model of a page, let's say a String object, and then use it in the model of a component.
To create the bean (or model instance), I call

```
<sly data-sly-use.model="myModel"/>
```

in the page and in the component
Problem is that I have now 2 instances with 2 sets of local data - what I do NOT want to have.

Answer (score 1):

The `SlingHttpServletRequest` (in general) provides an instance of `SlingBindings`, which contains a reference to `"currentPage"` (I am using the static field `WCMBindings.CURRENT_PAGE` [dependency: groupId: `com.adobe.cq.sightly`, artifactId: `cq-wcm-sightly-extension`, version: `1.2.30`] in my example).

The `Optional` I am using in my example is a Java 8 class which can be used to avoid too many checks for `null` references.

```
final Optional<Page> optional = Optional.ofNullable(request)
        .map(req -> (SlingBindings) req.getAttribute(SlingBindings.class.getName()))
        .map(b -> (Page) b.get(WCMBindings.CURRENT_PAGE));
```

A simplified/explicit example would be

```
Page getCurrentPageFromRequest(@Nonnull final SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
  final SlingBindings bindings = (SlingBindings) request.getAttribute(SlingBindings.class.getName())
  if (bindings == null) {
    return null;
  }
  return (Page) bindings.get(WCMBindings.CURRENT_PAGE);
}
```

In your Sling model you would just call

```
@Model(adaptables={ SlingHttpServletRequest.class, })
public class Model {

  public Model(@Nonnull final SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
    final Page currentPage = getCurrentPageFromRequest(request);
    // read properties.
  }

  Page getCurrentPageFromRequest(@Nonnull final SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
    final SlingBindings bindings = (SlingBindings) request.getAttribute(SlingBindings.class.getName())
    if (bindings == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return (Page) bindings.get(WCMBindings.CURRENT_PAGE);
  }
}
```

Comment: Florian, do you mean SlingHttpServletRequest?

Comment: Additional: I cannot find "cq-wcm-sightly-extension, version: 1.2.30" in the public Adobe Repos - so I think it's not publically available?

Comment: Yes, I did - fixed it. `cq-wcm-sightly-extension` should be deployed on you AEM instance, perhaps in a different version.